# Prove there is an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, orthogonality

Exercise 6.4.15 in Shifrin and Adams' Linear Algebra: a Geometric Approach says

> Suppose $A$ and $B$ are symmetric and $AB=BA$. Prove there is an orthogonal matrix $Q$ so that both $Q^{-1}AQ$ and $Q^{-1}BQ$ are diagonal. (*Hint*: Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalues of $A$. Use the Spectral Theorem to show that there is an orthonormal basis for **E**$(\lambda)$ consisting of eigenvectors of $B$.)

We know that if those two products of matrices were diagonal then $Q$ would be made of eigenvectors. Following the first part of the hint we know that $A$**x**$=\lambda$**x**. Can someone please solve this?

Comment: Sorry, but what is $\mathbf{E}(A)$ meant to indicate?

Comment: @DA29731: It's probably a (bad) notation for the eigenspace of $A$ associated with $\lambda$. Hint: If $AB=BA$ then the eigenspaces of $A$ are $B$-invariant.

Comment: @jazzinsilhouette Why do you think the notation is bad?

Comment: @QuinnCulver: I think this notation is "ok" if we know that $A$ has exactly one eigenvalue $\lambda$. However, in general this won't be the case and I think a meaningful notation for a general setting is something like $E_A(\lambda)$ or $E(A, \lambda)$. If it's clear which matrix we're talking about $E(\lambda)$ is okay too. But $E(A)$ carries almost no information.

Comment: @jazzinsilhouette Yes, you are right. The problem is that the post contained a typo. The book cited says $\mathbf{E}(\lambda)$, not $\mathbf{E}(A)$. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 1):

The spectral theorem in the textbook states that

> **Theorem. (Spectral Theorem).** 
>   *Let $A$ be a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix. Then*
>
> 1. *The eigenvalues of $A$ are real.*
> 2. *There is an orthonormal basis $\{{\bf q}_1,{\bf q}_2,\ldots,{\bf q}_n\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$
>      consisting of eigenvectors of $A$. That is, there is an orthogonal matrix
>      $Q$ so that $Q^{-1}AQ=\Lambda$ is diagonal.*

Now we start proving the **hint** of the problem. 
Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices, $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$,
and ${\bf E}(\lambda)$ be the $\lambda$-eigenspace of $A$.
Let 
$\beta=\{{\bf q}_1,{\bf q}_2,\ldots,{\bf q}_k\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ 
be an orthonormal basis for ${\bf E}(\lambda)$.
Since $AB=BA$,
given ${\bf x}\in{\bf E}(\lambda)$, we have
$$AB{\bf x}=BA{\bf x}=B\lambda{\bf x}=\lambda B{\bf x}.$$
It follows that $B{\bf x}\in{\bf E}(\lambda)$, that is,
$B({\bf E}(\lambda))\subseteq{\bf E}(\lambda)$ and we have a 
linear transformation $\mu_B:{\bf E}(\lambda)\rightarrow{\bf E}(\lambda)$
defined by $\mu_B({\bf x})=B{\bf x}$ for all ${\bf x}\in{\bf E}(\lambda)$.
Also, since 
$$B{\bf x}\cdot{\bf y}
={\bf x}^\top B^\top{\bf y}
={\bf x}^\top B{\bf y}
={\bf x}\cdot B{\bf y},\quad\forall
{\bf x},{\bf y}\in{\bf E}(\lambda).$$
By observing the following equations
\begin{align}
\mu_B({\bf q}_j)=B{\bf q}_j=\sum_{i=1}^k(B{\bf q}_j\cdot{\bf q}_i){\bf q}_i,\quad\forall j=1,2,\ldots,k,
\end{align}
if we let $B'$ be the $k\times k$ matrix for $\mu_B$ w.r.t. the 
basis $\beta$, that is,
$$B'=\begin{bmatrix}
B{\bf q}_1\cdot{\bf q}_1&
B{\bf q}_2\cdot{\bf q}_1&
\cdots&
B{\bf q}_k\cdot{\bf q}_1\\
B{\bf q}_1\cdot{\bf q}_2&
B{\bf q}_2\cdot{\bf q}_2&
\cdots&
B{\bf q}_k\cdot{\bf q}_2\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
B{\bf q}_1\cdot{\bf q}_k&
B{\bf q}_2\cdot{\bf q}_k&
\cdots&
B{\bf q}_k\cdot{\bf q}_k\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then $B'$ is symmetric,
and by the spectral theorem, there exists an orthonormal basis 
$\{{\bf q}'_1,{\bf q}'_2,\ldots,{\bf q}'_k\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^k$
consisting of eigenvectors of $B'$ corresponding to eigenvalues
$\mu_1,\mu_2,\ldots,\mu_k$. Define 
$\gamma=\{{\bf q}''_1,{\bf q}''_2,\ldots,{\bf q}''_k\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ by
$${\bf q}''_j=\sum_{i=1}^k({\bf q}'_j)_{i}{\bf q}_i,\quad\forall 
j=1,2,\ldots,k,$$
where $({\bf q}'_j)_i$ denote the $i$th entry of ${\bf q}'_j$.
Then $\gamma$ is clearly an orthonormal basis for ${\bf E}(\lambda)$. 
Moreover, observe that
\begin{align}
B{\bf q}''_j\cdot{\bf q}_l
=\sum_{i=1}^k({\bf q}'_j)_{i}(B{\bf q}_i\cdot{\bf q}_l)
=(B'{\bf q}'_j)_l
=(\mu_j{\bf q}'_j)_l
=\mu_j({\bf q}'_j)_l,
\end{align}
which implies
\begin{align}
B{\bf q}''_j\cdot{\bf q}''_l
&=\sum_{i=1}^k({\bf q}'_j)_{i}(B{\bf q}_i\cdot{\bf q}_l'')
=\sum_{i=1}^k({\bf q}'_j)_{i}(B{\bf q}''_l\cdot{\bf q}_i)\\
&=\mu_l\sum_{i=1}^k({\bf q}'_j)_{i}({\bf q}'_l)_i
=\mu_l{\bf q}'_j\cdot{\bf q}'_l
=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\mu_l&\mbox{if }j=l;\\0&\mbox{if }j\ne l.
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
Therefore 
$B{\bf q}''_j
=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k(B{\bf q}''_j\cdot{\bf q}''_i){\bf q}''_i
=\mu_j{\bf q}''_j$, that is, $\gamma$ consists of eigenvectors
of $B$, and we complete the proof of the hint.
The rest of the problem will follow immediately.